# Connecting OpenCV with CodeBlocks

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

I've followed a few guides, which, to be honest, generally.. all say the same thing.

Install MinGW, OpenCV, Codeblocks. Then through CodeBlocks' settings connect the two.

They all say, put the following directory in the CodeBlocks settings, a directory as the following opencv/build/x86/mingw.. however, when I go to the x86 folder, all I can see are two folders called vc11 and vc12. I do not have a mingw folder in the x86 folder in the opencv install directory.

I have lost my mind searching for this folder.

If anyone might know the answer to my question, or the solution to my problem, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV Doesn't come with pre-built MinGW libs. You have to compile it yourself using CMake. The VC folders are for the corresponding Visual Studio Compilers.

[This](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) is the installation guide on the OpenCV website

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. Gonna give it a shot. @GPPK